# Iterate Map in JXLS and Apache POI template

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxls

I would like to know is this possible to iterate map in JXLS.I tried with examples given in [**Link**](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/collectionsample.html), but I couldn't find way to iterate map.Please help me to find the solution.

**Sample Code in XLSX template:**

bomItemList-- List which has Event Objects.
supplierResponse-- Map of SupplierResponse Objects.

```
  <jx:forEach items="${bomItemList}" var="eventItemList" varStatus="status">
      <jx:forEach items="${eventItemList.supplierResponse}" var="supplierResponse" select="${supplierResponse.key > user}">
                    ${supplierResponse.supplierqty} 
      </jx:forEach>
  </jx:forEach>
```

**Output :(Inner forEach)**

```
<jx:forEach items="{supplier2=com.esource.vo.Supplierresponse@1489519, supplier1=com.esource.vo.Supplierresponse@34ca1a}" var="supplierResponse" select="false">

  </jx:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't iterate the `Map` directly, but you can iterate over the `Collection` of values that the map can supply.  Call the [`values()` method on the `Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--), which will return a `Collection` view of teh values that is suitable for iteration in JXLS.

```
<jx:forEach items="${eventItemList.supplierResponse.values()}" var="supplierResponse"
    select="${supplierResponse.key > user}">
```

Answer (score 2):

I use keySet() to iterate over map.

```
<jx:forEach items="${myMap.keySet()}" var="key1">
${myMap.get(key1).attr1}
</jx:forEach>
```

Comment: in jxls 2, there is no need to use `.attr1`